# How to use a vector to pass multiple strings into a function

Tags: c++, string, function, vector

I have a function that reads a file to find a certain word. The system I currently have however searched for a specific word and isn't case sensitive. I can't simply use .find("word" && "Word")

As far as I can tell, the easiest way to do this would be with a vector with both versions of the word inside for the function to look for both however I can't figure out how to pass the vector into the function.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not just always convert things to lower/upper case? Or are you not meant to handle "wOrd" and "WORD"? Then you'd just convert your string to lower case, and find the lower case variation of the word

Comment: I would recommend converting to lowercase or uppercase as well before you use find on the string, then you can find a single instance.  WORD WORd WOrd Word WOrD... etc gets complex quickly.  Especially if your "word" is actually longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can pass the vector to a function as a reference or absolute value. To pass as the reference, You can follow this approach.

```
int fun(std::vector<std::string>& arr) {
    int value = 0;
    // your operation
    return value;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    // your logic
    int value = fun(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just call find for every possible word in your vector. But i would suggest to use only lowercase if possible

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "HeLlo WorLd";
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "HELLO","HeLlo","hEllO","WORLD","WorLd" };

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const std::string& comp) 
    {
        auto found = str.find(comp);
        if (found != std::string::npos)
            std::cout << "Found World " << comp << " in str at " << std::distance(str.begin(), str.begin() + found) << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```